# JavaScript with addEventListener('keyup',)) not working on Web but working on jsfiddle, please assist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I tried my code in jsfiddle and it worked.

What basically I'm trying to do is to get credit card number and mask it except the 4 last digits (16 length), and if the credit card number starts with 3 it will have 15 length.

I think i missed something in the way.

Here is my code

```js
var ccNumInputElement = $("#ccNumInputField")[0];
var ccNumHiddenFieldID = "creditCardForm.creditCard.cardNumber";
var ccNumHiddemElement = document.getElementById(ccNumHiddenFieldID) == null ? "" :
  document.getElementById(ccNumHiddenFieldID);
var ccardnumber = "";
var ccardnumberArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
  "", "", ""
];
var ccardnumberLength = 0;

$(ccNumInputElement).on(addEventListener('keyup', processCCNum));

function processCCNum() {
  var inputControl = ccNumInputElement;
  var outputControl = ccNumHiddemElement;
  var ccardnumberMasked = "";

  ccardnumberLength = ccNumInputElement.value.length;

  var ccardnmmberLast = ccardnumberLength == 0 ? "" : inputControl.value
    .substring(ccardnumberLength - 1);

  var ccardnmmberFirst = ccardnumberLength == 0 ? "" : outputControl.value
    .substring(0, 1);

  if (ccardnumberLength == 0) {
    ccardnumberMasked = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
      ccardnumberArray[i] = "";
  }

  if (ccardnumberLength != 0) {
    if (ccardnmmberFirst == "3") {
      if (ccardnumberLength <= 11) {
        ccardnumberMasked = "***********".substring(0,
          ccardnumberLength);
        ccardnumberArray[ccardnumberLength - 1] = ccardnmmberLast;
      } else {
        ccardnumberMasked = "***********" +
          inputControl.value.substring(11);
        ccardnumberArray[ccardnumberLength - 1] = ccardnmmberLast;
      }

    } else {

      if (ccardnumberLength <= 12) {
        ccardnumberMasked = "************".substring(0,
          ccardnumberLength);
        ccardnumberArray[ccardnumberLength - 1] = ccardnmmberLast;
      } else {
        ccardnumberMasked = "************" +
          inputControl.value.substring(12);
        ccardnumberArray[ccardnumberLength - 1] = ccardnmmberLast;
      }
    }
    ccardnumber = "";
    if (ccardnmmberFirst == "3") {
      for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        ccardnumber = ccardnumber + ccardnumberArray[i];
      }
    } else {
      for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        ccardnumber = ccardnumber + ccardnumberArray[i];
      }
    }
    inputControl.value = ccardnumberMasked;

    outputControl.value = ccardnumber;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ccNumInputField" size="51" class="billinginfo" maxlength="16" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXXXX1234" />
<input type="hidden" name="creditCardForm.creditCard.cardNumber" id="creditCardForm.creditCard.cardNumber" />
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeonMelamud/wvyu5mfx/15/)

If you have better idea how to implement what I'm trying in JS, I will be grateful.

Comment: `not working on Web` What error?

Comment: `$(ccNumInputElement).on(addEventListener('keyup', processCCNum));` that's not the usual way to add event handlers...try `$(ccNumInputElement).on('keyup', processCCNum);`

Comment: if i removing addEventListener it not working at all

Comment: ccardnumberLength = ccNumInputElement.value.length;
getting next error:
"Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: also if im trying to get the value from outputControl
ccardnumberLength = outputControl.value.length;

getting   
Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, your function is fine except for the moment when you enter a number with first number 3.

You can just change `maxlength` and it works fine. I added this line

```js
inputControl.setAttribute("maxlength", "15");
```

in a condtition that checkcs if first number equals 3. And if it doesn't just set the attribute to 16.

**Here is an working example**

```js
var ccNumInputElement = $("#ccNumInputField")[0];
var ccNumHiddenFieldID = "creditCardForm.creditCard.cardNumber";
var ccNumHiddemElement = document.getElementById(ccNumHiddenFieldID) == null ? "" : document.getElementById(ccNumHiddenFieldID);
var ccardnumber = "";
var ccardnumberArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
var ccardnumberLength = 0;

$(ccNumInputElement).on(addEventListener('keyup', processCCNum));

function processCCNum() {
  var inputControl = ccNumInputElement;
  var outputControl = ccNumHiddemElement;
  var ccardnumberMasked = "";

  ccardnumberLength = ccNumInputElement.value.length;

  var ccardnmmberLast = ccardnumberLength == 0 ? "" : inputControl.value
    .substring(ccardnumberLength - 1);

  var ccardnmmberFirst = ccardnumberLength == 0 ? "" : outputControl.value
    .substring(0, 1);

  if (ccardnumberLength == 0) {
    ccardnumberMasked = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
      ccardnumberArray[i] = "";
  }

  if (ccardnumberLength != 0) {
    if (ccardnmmberFirst == "3") {
      if (ccardnumberLength <= 11) {
        ccardnumberMasked = "***********".substring(0,
          ccardnumberLength);
        ccardnumberArray[ccardnumberLength - 1] = ccardnmmberLast;
      } else {
        ccardnumberMasked = "***********" +
          inputControl.value.substring(11);
        ccardnumberArray[ccardnumberLength - 1] = ccardnmmberLast;
      }

    } else {

      if (ccardnumberLength <= 12) {
        ccardnumberMasked = "************".substring(0,
          ccardnumberLength);
        ccardnumberArray[ccardnumberLength - 1] = ccardnmmberLast;
      } else {
        ccardnumberMasked = "************" +
          inputControl.value.substring(12);
        ccardnumberArray[ccardnumberLength - 1] = ccardnmmberLast;
      }
    }
    ccardnumber = "";
    if (ccardnmmberFirst == "3") {
      inputControl.setAttribute("maxlength", "15");
      for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        ccardnumber = ccardnumber + ccardnumberArray[i];
      }
    } else {
      inputControl.setAttribute("maxlength", "16");
      for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        ccardnumber = ccardnumber + ccardnumberArray[i];
      }
    }
    inputControl.value = ccardnumberMasked;

    outputControl.value = ccardnumber;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ccNumInputField" size="51" class="billinginfo" maxlength="16" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXXXX1234" />
<input type="hidden" name="creditCardForm.creditCard.cardNumber" id="creditCardForm.creditCard.cardNumber" />
```

Comment: @leonmelamud If it helped you then please click the green chceck sign informing that you used that solution.

Comment: @leonmelamud you can always check the question :) No matter the rep

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the problem was in the initial variables in the start.
changed to

```
function processCCNum() {
    var inputControl = document.getElementById("ccNumInputField");
    var outputControl = document.getElementById("creditCardForm.creditCard.cardNumber");
```

i removed the

```
ccNumInputElement.on(addEventListener('keyup', processCCNum));
```

and add to the input onkeyup="processCCNum()"

```
<input type="text" id="ccNumInputField" size="51" class="billinginfo" maxlength="20" onkeyup="processCCNum()" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXXXX1234" />
```

this is working on IE11 but not working on jsfiddle for some reason.